# Не получается работать с Calendar API в Android +4.0

Tags: android, java

Может проблема в контент провайдере?

**content://com.android.calendar/calendars**

На других версиях работает отлично.

Какой есть способ, чтобы работал на всех версиях, где Calendar API задокументирован и нет?

Answer (score 1):

Не советую хардкодить урл контент-провайдера. Используйте константу:

```
CalendarContract.Calendars.CONTENT_URI
```

К тому же если мне не изменяет память Calendar API доступен только в ICS (4.0+), поэтому мне не совсем понятна сентенция:

> На других версиях работает отлично